# Markdown with fenced code blocks within lists has inconsistent previewed/final renderings

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

### About the bug

This is a bug whose effects you can see in [the revision history of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27534731/revisions). Specifically, it’s about the edit that created Revision 15 (click “side-by-side markdown” to see that edit’s changes).

The [rendered version of Revision 15](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27534731/15) wraps the text following my code blocks within code blocks of their own, and also adds empty code blocks in some places. However, when I was writing that Markdown in the code editor before saving that edit, those extra code blocks were not visible in the preview.

This is a bug because the JavaScript-rendered preview HTML should always match the server-rendered HTML. In this case, the JavaScript-rendered HTML had the better rendering of my Markdown, so the **server’s Markdown renderer should change**.

The Markdown I wrote included fenced code blocks within list items. That is a rare combination of formatting, so it is probably what triggered the bug in the server rendering. I will note that it *is* legal Markdown (according to CommonMark), and `<pre><code>` within an `<li>` *is* legal HTML (according to MDN’s summary of the spec).

### Bug reproduction

I was able to to reproduce that bug in the body of this question. In the JavaScript preview of the following Markdown, there are only **two** multi-line `pre`-wrapped code blocks. But in the rendered version, there are **four**:

---

- [**`console.log()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) (and its alias, [`console.info()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_info_data_args)):

  - **If the 1st argument is NOT a format string**: [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) is automatically applied to every argument:

    - ```
      o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} };
      console.log(o, [1,2,3])
      // ->  '{ one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: [Function] } [ 1, 2, 3 ]'
      ```

    ```
    * Note that you **cannot pass options** through `util.inspect()` in this case, which implies 2 notable limitations:
      * Structural **depth** of the output is **limited to *2* levels** (the default).
          * Since you cannot change this with `console.log()`, you must instead use `console.dir()`: **`console.dir(myObject, { depth: null }` prints with *unlimited* depth**; see below.
      * You can’t turn syntax coloring on.
    ```
  - **If the 1st argument IS a format string** (see below): uses [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) to print the remaining arguments based on the format string (see below); e.g.:

    - ```
      o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} };
      console.log('o as JSON: %j', o)
      // ->  'o as JSON: {"one":1,"two":"deux"}'
      ```

    ```
    * Note:
      * There is NO placeholder for representing _objects_ `util.inspect()`-style.
      * JSON generated with `%j` is NOT pretty-printed.
    ```
- [**`console.dir()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options):

  - …